# How to write a sufficient program for weed lawn problem?

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to write a program for the problem below :

you have a lawn (a matrix of n*m) and in some cells, weed has grown, and you want to remove them.
there are two operations :

1. stomping on a cell: by doing so, one of the weeds in that cell dies and two new weeds appear in cells `[i][(j+1)%n)` and `[(i+1)%n][j]`.
2. pulling out a weed: this removes the weed and takes the energy of `E_(i,j)`.

Now given a matrix of energy(how much energy removing one weed from each cell takes) and the places where weeds have grown, we want to calculate the least amount of energy we need to get rid of all the weeds.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;  
import java.io.*;

public class TEST{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int n=0, m=0 , k=0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        m = scanner.nextInt();
        k = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        int [][] lawn = new int [n][m];
        int [][] NumOfWeed = new int [n][m];

        for(int j=0; j<m ; j++){
            for(int i=0; i < n ; i ++){
                lawn[i][j]= scanner.nextInt();
            }
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        int i_index =0, j_index =0;
        for(int i=0; i < k ; i ++){
            i_index= scanner.nextInt();
            j_index=scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            NumOfWeed[i_index][j_index] ++;
        }
        boolean changing = true;
        while(changing){
            changing = false;
            for(int j=0; j<m ; j++){
                for(int i=0; i < n ; i ++){
                    if(NumOfWeed[i][j]>0){
                        if(lawn[i][j] > lawn[(i+1)%n][j]+lawn[i][(j+1)%n]){
                            NumOfWeed[(i+1)%n][j] =NumOfWeed[(i+1)%n][j] + NumOfWeed[i][j];
                            NumOfWeed[i][(j+1)%n] = NumOfWeed[i][(j+1)%n] + NumOfWeed[i][j];
                            NumOfWeed[i][j]=0;
                            changing = true;
                         }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }

        int sumEnergy =0;

        for(int j=0; j<m ; j++){
            for(int i=0; i < n ; i ++){
                sumEnergy = sumEnergy + lawn[i][j]*NumOfWeed[i][j];
            }
        }

        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(sumEnergy);
    }
}
```

you can see my own code above, but as you see it's not optimal at all.
any ideas on how I can change it so that it takes less time to perform?

Comment: Same inputs and outputs and input size constraints would be helpful. `Scanner` isn't reproducible -- better to hardcode at least one test case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it, that should lead to correct results but isn't optimized:

1. Initialize a matrix `a` (size n * m) for the actual energy needed if you stomp optimally. Set all values to -1.
2. Find all minima in the original energy matrix ignoring values where the corresponding position in `a` is not -1. Set the positions of the minima in `a` to its value.
3. While there are changes and `a` isn't completely filled do the following: For each value (i, j) in `a` that is -1 and the values to the right and down (with wrap-around) are not -1 set (i, j) to the minimum of the sum of the 2 stomped position and the original energy needed for (i, j).
4. Continue with 2. until `a` is completely filled. Then "multiply" the lawn matrix with `a` (no matrix multiplication, just same position with same position) and sum up the values to get the total.